# Number replace pattern issue with RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the string `page-24` and want to replace `24` by any other number.

The script is written in PHP and uses `preg_replace`, however this problem should be independent from the programming language.

My match pattern is: `(.*-)(\d*)`

The replace pattern would be: `$1[insert number here]$2`

The backreferences work, but I cannot insert a number into the given place in the replace pattern because the expression would be interpreted in a wrong way. (First backreference to 199th match, if I inserted 99 as number.)

Am I missing an escape character here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, the replacement string either looks like this:

```
'${1}[insert number here]$2'
```

Or like this (if it is in a double-quoted string):

```
"\${1}[insert number here]$2"
```

Example:

```
$s = 'page-24';
$out = preg_replace('/(.*-)(\d*)/', '${1}99$2', $s);
echo "out is $out"; //prints 'page-9924'
```

<sup>(You probably just want `${1}99`, which would give `'page-99'` rather than `'page-9924'`.)</sup>

See [here for documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in PHP.  Perl uses the same notation. Javascript, as far as I can tell, doesn't support the `${1}` notation, but it will interpret `$199` as `${199}` if there are at least 199 matching parenthesis, as `${19}9` if there are at least 19 matching parens, and `${1}99` if there is at least 1 matching paren, or the literal string `$199` if there are no matches. I don't know about other languages' implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use match pattern

```
(.*)-(\d*)
```

and replace pattern

```
$1-[new number]
```

Why is there a reference to $2 in the replace pattern if you want to replace it?